# Unity3d from a list, get only entities of specific component type

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine

I know that if I have something like

```
Component tmp = (myClass)gameObject.GetComponent<myClass>();
```

can return either a null value, or an instance of the typed "myClass" if it exists on my specific game object.  Now, lets assume I have an array of objects from a Physics Sphere Capture of a given radius.  I have 20 game objects returned.

How can I create a  routine to only return those game objects that have a component of  so I don't have to write my own iterator over and over.  Again being generics because in one area I may want  another  and yet another place .  I don't want to be throwing typecasting all over to make the readability a pain.

FEEDBACK (per Ciprian's answer)

I tried your approach verbatim and was not getting any that were of the "Class" I wanted even though it was an attached component.  So, I tried to modify the routine slightly.  First, ensure a proper "GameObject". Then from that, try to call the `GameObject's  .GetComponent<T>()`. but that is causing an error, even though the `<T>` is the same type I am looking for via get Component.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetItemsAsT<T>(this object[] objects) 
        where T:class
    {
        GameObject gObj;
        foreach(var obj in objects)
        {
            if( obj is GameObject )
            {
                gObj = (GameObject)obj;
                if( gObj.GetComponent<T>() != null )
                {
                    Debug.Log ( "Found via IEnumerable" );
                    yield return gObj.GetComponent<T>();
                }
            }
        }
        yield break;
    }
```

Per slight revision to Ciprian's answer.

```
Error CS0311: The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'UnityEngine.GameObject.GetComponent<T>()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'T' to 'UnityEngine.Component'. (CS0311) (Assembly-CSharp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now I think I understood your problem so this is why I post as a separate answer.

You have a composite object, and you want to call a custom action based on a mix of custom class "attributes" that exist in a game object.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetItemsAsT<T>(this GameObject[] objects) 
    where T:UnityEngine.Component
    {
        foreach(var obj in objects)
        {
            var t = obj.GetComponent<T>();
            if(t != null)
                yield return t;
        }
        yield break;
    }
```

I updated the changes and remove the unnecesary casts from your answer. The single important changes from the questions are:

- use GameObject[] array to not make your casts by hand
- use where T:Component instead of T:class

Comment: Thanks, revised question, will try at home later, but think it is because I was missing the "where T : class" clause

Comment: I tried and updated my post with the revised implementation.  Can you look into it and see if it makes sense to you?

Comment: Updated answer after feedback

Comment: will try again when I get home tonight, but I don't know how Unity is considering a class as a component, but I'm still learning and very early in on it.

Comment: Which was the result?

Comment: I revised my original post and it has a compile error about the type 'T'.  See revised post with code and actual error message

Comment: Sorry, are you sure you added: where T: Component

If so: change to 
    where T: UnityEngine.Component

Comment: Yup, it worked when classifying it as a COMPONENT and not a class as in your original answer/post.

Answer (score 1):

I understood that you need two code cases that can be implemented to an array of object:

```
static class GenericUtils
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetItemsAsT<T>(this object[] objects) 
    where T:class
    {
        foreach(var obj in objects)
        {
            var t = obj as T;
            if(t != null)
                yield return t;
        }
        yield break;
    }
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetItemsWhere<T>(this object[] objects, Predicate<T> predicate) 
        where T:class
    {
        foreach(var tObj in objects.GetItemsAsT<T>())
        {
            if(predicate(tObj))
            {
                yield return tObj;
            }
        }
        yield break;
    }
}
```

To use them, you can either get let's say a list of circles:

```
items.GetItemsAsT<Circle>();
```

or use a predicate to filter them:

```
items.GetItemsWhere<Circle>(c => c.Radius < 30);
```

All items are IEnumerable so if you need to convert them to array, use the .ToArray(), or to use them as a List use .ToList()

**Later**
If you are familiar with Linq, you can use just the first method and later use Linq combined functions so the last line of code you can rewrite as:

```
items.GetItemsAsT<Circle>().Where(c => c.Radius < 30);
```

Also, if your name GetItemsAsT is verbose, chose just a shorter name for them: AsT.

Comment: Looks promising, but if I have a game object with 3 class scripts associated with it, how/where are you confirming that the overall game object contains one of the components I am specifically looking for.  I cant confirm which "myGameObject is someClass" if 3 are attached, I had to go to the specific GetComponent<classIWanted>() to see if associated, THEN work with that component part.